# AMD Ryzen 2600 temperature

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers, temperature, sensors

I have installed it87 module and here is my `sensors` output

```
asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:        0 RPM

it8665-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:          +0.65 V  (min =  +1.12 V, max =  +1.11 V)  ALARM
in1:          +2.52 V  (min =  +2.14 V, max =  +0.42 V)  ALARM
in2:          +2.04 V  (min =  +1.64 V, max =  +0.13 V)  ALARM
in3:          +1.98 V  (min =  +2.77 V, max =  +1.47 V)  ALARM
in4:          +0.03 V  (min =  +0.60 V, max =  +1.61 V)  ALARM
in5:          +0.03 V  (min =  +1.26 V, max =  +1.70 V)  ALARM
in6:          +0.03 V  (min =  +1.59 V, max =  +1.54 V)  ALARM
3VSB:         +3.38 V  (min =  +1.24 V, max =  +2.90 V)  ALARM
Vbat:         +3.29 V  
+3.3V:        +3.38 V  
fan1:         972 RPM  (min =  463 RPM)
fan2:        1005 RPM  (min =   13 RPM)
fan3:         981 RPM  (min =   11 RPM)
fan4:           0 RPM  (min =   -1 RPM)
fan6:           0 RPM  (min =   -1 RPM)
temp1:        +26.0°C  (low  = +117.0°C, high = +87.0°C)
temp2:        +26.0°C  (low  = -31.0°C, high = +99.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp3:        +29.0°C  (low  = +55.0°C, high = -67.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermistor
temp4:        +29.0°C  (low  = +44.0°C, high =  +1.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermistor
temp5:        +29.0°C  (low  = -119.0°C, high = +67.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp6:        +29.0°C  (low  = -118.0°C, high = -11.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermistor
intrusion0:  ALARM

nouveau-pci-0600
Adapter: PCI adapter
GPU core:     +0.91 V  (min =  +0.80 V, max =  +1.19 V)
temp1:        +37.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +75.8°C  (high = +70.0°C)
```

I want to know what is this value responsible for

```
k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +75.8°C  (high = +70.0°C)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is driver of a thermal sensors on processors from AMD-family chips. If you run `sensors-detect` you should see something like

```
Driver `k10temp' (built-in):
  * Chip `AMD Family 15h thermal sensors' (confidence: 9)
```

and `lspci -v` returns which device uses this driver:

```
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b3
        Flags: fast devsel
        Capabilities: [f0] Secure device <?>
        Kernel driver in use: k10temp
```

You can read full documentation of this driver in `"/usr/src/linux-$(uname -r)/Documentation/hwmon/k10temp"`, in particular a list of supported chips:

> - AMD Family 10h processors:   Socket F: Quad-Core/Six-Core/Embedded Opteron (but see below)   Socket AM2+: Quad-Core Opteron, Phenom (II)
>     X3/X4, Athlon X2 (but see below)   Socket AM3: Quad-Core Opteron,
>     Athlon/Phenom II X2/X3/X4, Sempron II   Socket S1G3: Athlon II,
>     Sempron, Turion II
> - AMD Family 11h processors:   Socket S1G2: Athlon (X2), Sempron (X2), Turion X2 (Ultra)
> - AMD Family 12h processors: "Llano" (E2/A4/A6/A8-Series)
> - AMD Family 14h processors: "Brazos" (C/E/G/Z-Series)
> - AMD Family 15h processors: "Bulldozer" (FX-Series), "Trinity", "Kaveri", "Carrizo"
> - AMD Family 16h processors: "Kabini", "Mullins"

Comment: but is it normal that it temperature is 70 - 80 degree while doing nothing on computer?

Comment: lspci output : 00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 3
 Flags: fast devsel
 Kernel driver in use: k10temp
 Kernel modules: k10temp

Comment: @karim Mine normally shows 30-40 while "doing nothing", rises to 50-60 when watching youtube in higher resolution, more than 60 only when I'm compiling something bigger. Does your fan work properly, do you hear it?

Comment: yeah i have 2 case fan and the cpu fan working at 800 - 1000 rpm, and the value of this temperature show that the cpu is cool, think temp1:        +26.0°C  (low  = +117.0°C, high = +87.0°C)
temp2:        +26.0°C  (low  = -31.0°C, high = +99.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp3:        +29.0°C  (low  = +55.0°C, high = -67.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermistor
temp4:        +29.0°C  (low  = +44.0°C, high =  +1.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermistor
temp5:        +29.0°C  (low  = -119.0°C, high = +67.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp6:        +29.0°C  (low  = -118.0°C, high = -11.0°C)  ALARM  sensor =

Comment: and i think there is a problem with sensors compatibility or something like that, because in windows using speedfan, my cpu temperature show 35 degree.   and in linux it show 75 degree and the the cpu fan is not detected even if it running Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:        0 RPM

Comment: @karim you can look directly at `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/temp1_input` (change hwmon2 to some other value) to double check that `sensors` doesn't change this value somehow (very unlikely, but still). Also take a look at your kernel parameters (/usr/src/linux/.config), in my case besides CONFIG_SENSORS_K10TEMP I had to set also CONFIG_SENSORS_FAM15H_POWER (both are inside Device Drivers -> Hardware Monitoring Support).

Comment: just checked /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/temp1_input, look the same, 7800 ==> 78.00 degree, i have openeed my computer case, and touched the fan heatpipes and found they are cold, so i think that just a problem with reading the value from the motherboard

Comment: just checked temperature in bios directly after shuting down computer, and it was 81 Fahren it mean 28 celcuis, so i think there is a bug that don't convert this value to celcuis

Comment: @karim Check what chip exactly is responsible for readings by visual inspection (this is south bridge I believe) and check on https://hwmon.wiki.kernel.org/device_support_status if there are know issues with it.